# Time tracking data mismatch

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-tracking

I'm trying to get into python and using Mark Lutz's "Learning python" for this. I'm on time tracking exercizes right now.

Here are the functions which I use to make time tracking (those are just copies from the book):

```
    import time, sys
    trace = lambda *args: None  # or print
    timefunc = time.clock if sys.platform == 'win32' else time.time

    def timer(func, *pargs, _reps=1000, **kargs):
        trace(func, pargs, kargs, _reps)
        start = timefunc()
        for i in range(_reps):
            ret = func(*pargs, **kargs) 
        elapsed = timefunc() - start
        return (elapsed, ret)

    def best(func, *pargs, _reps=50, **kargs):
        best = 2 ** 32
        for i in range(_reps):
            (time, ret) = timer(func, *pargs, _reps=1, **kargs)
            if time < best: best = time
        return (best, ret)
```

I test three ways of getting a square root of a number: `math.sqrt`, `x**.5` and `pow(x, .5)`

Here's my main file:

```
from math import sqrt
import mytimer

def stars(x):
    return x ** .5

def power(x):
    return pow(x, .5)

sqrtmath = mytimer.best(sqrt, 15000, _reps = 1000000)
print(sqrtmath, '\n')

sqrtstars = mytimer.best(stars, 15000, _reps = 1000000)
print(sqrtstars, '\n')

sqrtpow = mytimer.best(power, 15000, _reps = 1000000)
print(sqrtpow, '\n')

sqrtmatha = mytimer.timer(sqrt, 15000, _reps = 1000000)
print(sqrtmatha, '\n')

sqrtstarsa = mytimer.timer(stars, 15000, _reps = 1000000)
print(sqrtstarsa, '\n')

sqrtpowa = mytimer.timer(power, 15000, _reps = 1000000)
print(sqrtpowa, '\n')
```

I'm getting a result similar to this:

```
math.sqrt best (3.0419786956059625e-07, 122.47448713915891) 

** best        (3.0419786956059625e-07, 122.47448713915891) 

pow best       (6.083957391211925e-07, 122.47448713915891) 

math.sqrt sum  (0.23758340345094187, 122.47448713915891) 

** sum         (0.4220751526921207, 122.47448713915891) 

pow sum        (0.48036463590252776, 122.47448713915891)
```

As you can see, the best times are completely identical for math.sqrt and ** versions, but the difference in cumulative time for them is pretty sighnificant. How can this be? Is there a my mistake somewhere? Is there some hidden python mechanism I don't know about?

Comment: The excercise probably isn't designed for you to make conclusions on the results but to practice writing and using functions (? guessing, not familiar with the book).  If you want to see more accurate results, use the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module to Measure execution time of small code snippets.  The docs are pretty good, try it.

Comment: My only guess for now is that functions take so little time to execute, that program can't properly see the difference.

Comment: Or every once in a while, the operating system decides to steal some processing time to do some other random thing.

Comment: Those functions were giving pretty reasonable results for the inputs, which take longer to execute. After testing a few more times I realised, that sometimes `**` best is exactly equal to `pow` result, which makes me think that the timeframe of execution is really just too small. Thanks for the advice though!